# Do MySQL can do automatic EXPLAIN on every query?

Tags: mysql

We only have two Junior DBAs, no Senior DBAs, no one to guide us. We need to review each and every query for almost 30 large projects. Each query took between 5 minutes and two hours depending on the query. As a reviewer, it was a real drag on my time.

My question is, do MySQL can do automatic EXPLAIN on each query, without having to run EXPLAIN by hand and log the result of un-optimized queries? Or maybe by cronjob? If possible, how to do this?

Comment: if using mariadb there is [log-slow-verbosity=query_plan,explain](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/explain-in-the-slow-query-log/)

Comment: [pt-query-digest](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-query-digest.html) can help optimize the slow ones and include cut/paste SQL for explain.

Comment: fwiw, i'd enable the slow query log, set a short long_query_time and use pt-query-digest to prioritize it down from longest consumed. All queries is excessive. Report your milestones and then drop the long_query_time more. Consider tools like [cluster control](https://severalnines.com/product/clustercontrol/clustercontrol-community-edition)

Comment: If the answer is acceptable to you please accept it as an answer. If not request further information. Welcome to SO, a programming side. DBA questions are more suited to https://dba.stackexchange.com/ where they will get more attention.

Comment: @danblack , I have already asked the same question in dba StackExchange https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/270419/do-mysql-can-do-automatic-explain-on-every-query?noredirect=1#comment532318_270419 ...    Still not receiving suitable answer

Comment: You don't seem to have answered back on your suitability criteria or even basic questions like the mysql version? There good organization questions to why this task is so broad or firmly on your shoulders and its in your hands to push back as say what is and isn't possible. Asking how to phrase those questions as a solo junior DBA is an appropriate question. Not saying anything is going to cause you to fail and the organization to loose too. You aren't doing anyone a favour by accepting the task as its currently scoped.

Comment: @danblack I cannot put my comment on DBA StackExchange, since must have 50 reputation to put my comment, that's why I cannot reply to their question

Answer (score 1):

If using mariadb there is [log-slow-verbosity=query_plan,explain](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/explain-in-the-slow-query-log/).

Alternately [pt-query-digest](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-query-digest.html#cmdoption-pt-query-digest-explain) has an `--explain` option to point to the server to run the explain query.

Comment: I have to read more about pt-query-digest, since my CTO did not prefer to enable the slow log...  So I have to do more reading on this to convince him...

Comment: can I just using the performance report, with this pt-query-digest?

Comment: While there are other sources that pt-query-digest can use, the slow query log is low overhead. It just needs to write a small amount of text to a unbuffered file when the time exceeds the `long-query-time`, so don't set it to 0, start with 1 second or so to start with. Do NOT enable `log_queries_not_using_indexes`, that will cause too much.